# system agnostic url encoding

Tags: java, encoding

I have a web application that performs GET requests to another web application. In one of my pages, I have a web form where I can search by name, and that might include special chars like áéíóú, etc.

The problem is, if I build my URI by concatenation of the different params, the result is wrongly encoded. If I use URLEncoder.encode(value) then the result is correctly encoded, but this method is deprecated.

If I specify the encoding, like URLEncoder.encode(value, "iso 9809-1") then it works, but to my understanding this is very system dependent.

How can I work out a URL encoding solution that works on all systems?

Comment: What makes you think that `URLEncoder.encode(value, "iso 9809-1")` is system dependent?

Comment: Default HTTP request/response application protocols *should* use `UTF-8` internally (not all systems). You can safely *assume* `UTF-8` is a safer bet.

Comment: The method you mention is not only deprecated, it is deprecated in favour of another method which (a) is explicitly mentioned in the deprecation tag and (b) appears in the same page of Javadoc. I suggest you should have read it rather than waste time here.

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated version without encoding uses the platform specific encoding.

"ISO-8859-1" (Latin-1) is the default encoding of the HTTP protocols. That is more of less a subset of "Windows-1252" (Windows Latin-1). And covers some of the Western European languages like English and German.

"UTF-8" would be best, but maybe not supported by you server. Try it.

Comment: did not know about iso being default encoding. UTF-8 does not work for me. Thanks!

Comment: That's why java EE servers still have to be configured for UTF-8, the best candidate for a universal encoding (UTF-16 not being more compact for Asian scripts because of the HTML tags).